# Modify sidebar information caused by marker click

Tags: leaflet

First time poster here, hopefully someone can point me in the right direction! Pretty new to Leaflet, HTML, and CSS in general so this project has been a great learning experience for me but I've really hit a roadblock at this point.

I'm using Leaflet to create a WebMap of a walking tour for a local town. http://beattyre.github.io/WebMapTest/ I have pictures, points, and descriptions stored in a GeoJSON file and have created a webpage for testing purposes as I work on this project. Basically, what I hope to do, is to have the sidebar information to be populated with the GeoJSON attributes when I click on a point, rather than create a pop-up with the information. I've seen it done before on other webmaps such as this one http://benjmyers.com/ratmap/#/, but am having trouble figuring out how it's done. I think I've discovered that AngularJS is the library is what I need to accomplish this, but I'm not quite sure how. Can anyone point me in the right direction or give me some tips on how to create this feature?

Comment: start simple, just use html and css to create the sidebar and javascript (with or without jquery) to update it.